# Rcpp First Compilation trouble

Tags: c++, r, compiler-construction, fibonacci, rcpp

I recently downloaded the 2013 Rcpp book off amazon to learn how to use C++ with my R code better and I'm trying the first compilation example with the first fibonacci recursion function and wrapper to see if I can do it. I'm on Ubuntu with the latest R.

First my C++:

```
    /* Cpp based recurive function */
int fibonacci(const int x){
  if(x == 0) return(0);
  if(x == 1) return(1);
  return(fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2));
}


/* Wrapper */
extern "C" SEXP fibWrapper(SEXP xs) {
  int x = Rcpp::as<int>(xs);
  int fib = fibonacci(x);
  return(Rcpp::wrap(fib));
}
```

Then I start sh and type in:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()'`
PKG_LIBS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'`
R CMD SHLIB Fibonacci.cpp
```

But I get:

```
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c Fibonacci.cpp -o Fibonacci.o
Fibbonacci.cpp:10:12: error: 'SEXP' does not name a type
make: *** [Fibonacci.o] Error 1
```

I figure maybe I need the include directive in my C++ code, so I do it again, but this time with `#include<Rcpp.h>` at the top of the C++ file, and do the same commands in sh again, but still no joy:

```
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c Fibonacci.cpp -o Fibonacci.o
Fibonacci.cpp:1:18: fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Fibbonacci.o] Error 1
```

What have I done wrong?
If I query the values I've set in sh:

```
$PKG_CXXFLAGS
sh: 9: -I/local/yrq12edu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/include: not found
$PKG_LIBS
sh: 10: -L/local/yrq12edu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rcpp/lib: not found
```

But I think the not found messages are just because of the -L flag since the files are there if I cd to the directory.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this, presumably something like: `Rcpp:::SHLIB("fibbonacci.cpp")` in the directory containing the cpp file?

Comment: Just tried it with Rcpp:::SHLIB as is the suggestion by you and this blog post: http://www.computerbastard.com/rcpp-c-compilation-trick/ I get the following: `$ Rscript -e "Rcpp:::SHLIB('fibbonacci.cpp')"
make: *** No rule to make target `fibbonacci.o', needed by `fibbonacci.so'. Stop`

Comment: For what it is worth, I completely disagree wit the Rcpp::SHLIB suggestion.  It might as well be removed here.

Comment: Sorry that I forget `Rcpp:::SHLIB` is suggested for Windows. The comment is removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have overlooked an important detail. When you do

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()'`
PKG_LIBS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'`
R CMD SHLIB Fibonacci.cpp
```

the result of the first two should be assigned and exported to the shell. What you do here "assigns and forgets".

What you missed from Listing 2.1 which shows this (or maybe the e-book dropped it -- I do not have the e-book) is the *very important* trailing backslash which makes everything a single line:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()'` \
PKG_LIBS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'`  \
R CMD SHLIB Fibonacci.cpp
```

Now the assignments happen in the same execution as the call to R (a shell script itself), it has the values and it passes them in the call to g++.

You can tell by the next two lines in which I fully quote the resulting commands which have all the required -I and -L pieces. Hence both (the compile and link step) go over multiple lines.

So the book is correct, and all this works if done the way showns.  Both inline (discussed later in the chapter) and attributes (also discussed later in the same chapter) basically make the `PKG_CXXFLAGS` and `PKG_LIBS` assignments for you.

Edit: Also, your testing is wrong. What you meant may have been this

```
$ PKG_CXXFLAGS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()'`
$ echo $PKG_CXXFLAGS
-I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include
$
```

You can't just 'invoke' a shell variable, hence the 'not found' answer you got.

Edit 2:  In any event, the example you tried is really just there to motivate the rest of the discussion in Section 2.4 which details just how laborious, error-prone, ... this is -- leading to Sections 2.5 and 2.6 about inline and Attributes.  Both are much better; use those.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @DirkEddelbuettel, and the pointer to Rcpp attributes, Romain. I re-did the process with the backslashes and it works (you are right I forgot to mention the echo command).

Comment: Glad to hear it works. Attributes are covered in Sections 1.2.5 and 2.6 which should get you started.  See the vignette that came with Rcpp for full details; the book examples all work fine albeit mostly use inline.

Answer (score 1):

How did you install R ? It looks like you are missing R headers. Perhaps you need to install the [`r-base-dev` package](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/).

About the code, you don't need the wrapper. You can just put this in a `.cpp` file :

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int fibonacci(const int x){
  if(x == 0) return(0);
  if(x == 1) return(1);
  return(fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2));
}
```

and just `sourceCpp` this file :

```
> sourceCpp( "fib.cpp" )
> fibonacci(6)
[1] 8
```

Comment: Ok I'll give this a try, I tried it the way I did because I'm on Loc 1318 of 5640 of the Rcpp ebook - Listing 2.2.

Comment: Sure. Unfortunately, attributes (the `[[Rcpp::export]]` decoration) came during (and near the end) of Dirk writing the book, so they are not shown much in the book. They are however what we encourage people to use these days. For example, all examples in the Rcpp gallery use attributes.

Comment: @RomainFrancois: Your first line there is just wrong.  The compiler tells him Rcpp.h is missing, not R.h.  He has the right R package; he didn't communicate the `-I` flag correctly.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Right. I was confused by "Fibbonacci.cpp:10:12: error: 'SEXP' does not name a type"

Comment: @RomainFrancois: That is the OP's mistake as the code he copied from has the required `#include` he then adds.